# javafx - Scale horizontal length according to horizontal length of scrollpane

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

So I have this FXML code here (generated via SceneBuilder):

http://pastebin.com/0mjBh9s7

The problem is that I want the content inside the GridPane to scale horizontally according to the horizontal size of the Scroll Pane, but the scaling does not work.

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi Ben. People should not be surfing to an off-site resource to be able to view your code. Please [edit] your question, paste the code in your question and format it with the `{}` button. Make sure the code is a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

You do not scale anything in that fxml, nor does scaling work, since it does not influence the `layoutBounds` property that `ScrollPane` uses to determine the size of the content.

For this reason you'd need to wrap the `GridPane` in a `Group` for the `ScrollPane` to see the size of `GridPane` including scale transformations.

If you do not want to scale the content, but simply resize it to the viewport size of the `ScrollPane`, setting [the `fitToWidth` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#fitToWidthProperty) to `true` would be the appropriate way to handle this.

Comment: How do I wrap the GridPane into a Group? After that, what's next?

Comment: @BenTinner In SceneBuilder select the content of the `ScrollPane`, i.e. the `GridPane`, in the *Hierarchy View*, open the context mentu and select `Wrap In > Group` and then set the scale properties of the `GridPane` or (as in exclusive or) select the `ScrollPane` and check the *fit to Width* check box in the layout part to make the `GridPane` always be resized to the width of the `ScrollPane`'s content area.